# Getting post-build event errors on running FxCopCmd.exe

Tags: fxcopcmd

I have used this line for my post-build to run FxCopCmd.exe:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft FxCop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe" /file:"$(TargetPath)" /console
```

but after I build the project it shows this error:

Error 40 The command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft FxCop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe" /file:"C:\csharpForFXCOP\MyTestPrj\bin\MyTestPrj.exe" /console" exited with code 9009.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the same command line from a Windows command prompt.  If the additional information this provides is not sufficient for you to identify the problem, please add the details to your post.

Comment: cannot! it is in post build so it knows which assembly I am working on but if I go to command line then after going to fxcop folder the command is like "FxCopCmd.exe" /file:"$(TargetPath)" /console"  which does not know which C# project to build

Comment: You included the literal command line in your post, so you actually do know what it is.